# Python IDLE freezes when invoking File > New Window

Tags: python, python-idle

I am running Mac OS X Snow Leopard ( version 10.6.4 )
with Python Version 2.6.1
               Tk Version 8.5
            IDLE Version 2.6.1

If I launch IDLE and enter Python statements in the initial window that is presented, all seems fine.

However, if, in the IDLE session, I invoke the menu item File > New Window
a new window does appear, but I can not type anything into it, and, worse yet, can not type anything into
the original IDLE session window either, and have to do a force quit.

Does anyone have any suggestions as to how to properly use the File > New Window feature of IDLE on the Mac?

Comment: [you might want to report a bug](http://bugs.python.org/)

Comment: This particular problem appears to have been limited to 2.6.  However, there have been similar issues due to problems with the Apple-supplied tcl/tk.  Mac users with problems should check https://www.python.org/download/mac/tcltk/.

Answer (score 1):

It's a [bug](http://bugs.python.org/issue6864) (also reported [here](http://bugs.python.org/issue8381)).